# Replacing all occurrences of a word with another

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing  a regex to match every occurrence of "japan" and replace it with "Japan" .. why doesn't the below work ? And "japan" can occur multiple times in a sentence and anywhere in a sentence. I want to replace all occurrences

```
public static void testRegex()
{
    String input = "The nonprofit civic organization shall comply with all other requirements of section 561.422, japan laws, in obtaining the temporary permits authorized by this act.";
    String regex = "japan";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(input.matches(regex));
    System.out.println(input.replaceAll(regex, "Japan"));

}
```

Comment: what output do you get when you run this?

Comment: What doesn't work here? Your replaceAll seems fine to me.

Comment: The regex match evaluates to false.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need regex here, and neither Pattern and Matcher classes. Simple use of `String.replace()` will work fine:

```
input = input.replace("japan", "Japan");
```

Comment: I have to use regex because this is an external api that I am using

Comment: @Phoenix. Still it doesn't convince me to use regex. In what way you are using the api?

Comment: it is configured through spring

Comment: I'd favour using `StringUtils.replace()` from apache commons for nicely handling `null` values

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll` is working as intended.

From your comment:

> The regex match evaluates to false.

This statement evaluates to `false`

```
System.out.println(input.matches(regex));
```

as `String#matches` matches the complete `String`.  Since the `String` `"japan"` is not a regex, you could do

```
System.out.println(input.contains(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

`input.matches(regex)` *auto-anchors* your pattern with `^` and `$`. Simply surround your pattern with `.*` to have matches.

But then, the `replaceAll` won't work anymore. Thus, you'll have to replace `(.*?)japan(.*?)` by `$1Japan$2`.